# Making a JFrame act like a dialog box

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have a form for the user to fill out in a JFrame which then writes the collected data to a JTable in a different class.

I'm trying to configure it that when the user selects "Submit" that the JFrame will close, but not close down the program. What would be the command I need to achieve this?

The code for the submit button is as follows is as follows:

```
JButton bMark = new JButton("Submit");
    bMark.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String start = tbStart.getText();
            String end = tbEnd.getText();

            String[] marking = {start, end, active, body, dysk, trem, brady};

            //This is just for me to ensure the collected data is correct
            System.out.println(marking[0] + " " +marking[1] + " " +marking[2] + " " + 
                    marking[3] + " " + marking[4] + " " + marking[5] + " " + marking[6]);

            //This is is the class the form data is being sent to
            markTable.main(marking);

            //This is where I would like the close the current window

        }
    });
    bMark.setBounds(308, 191, 86, 23);
```

The class name is createMark and the method is public createMark

Thanks to anyone who replies,

Jared.

Comment: *"Making a JFrame act like a dialog box"*  You can't make a silk purse from a sow's ear.  **Use a `JDialog`!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [default close operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) on the JFrame as such:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

This will take care of the case where the user closes the window using the title bar or hits something like Alt+F4.

Next, simply call `setVisible(false)` when the submit button is pressed.

Comment: @Jazibobs: why the heck aren't you simply using a JDialog? You've never addressed this. This makes *no* sense at all. Do you understand that a JDialog can hold as complex a GUI as any JFrame, plus it has other advantages in how the operating system handles it (as it is "owned" by the parent window)?

Answer (score 4):

> //This is where I would like the close the current window

there are these ways

- `JFrame#setVisible(false)`, but not terminating current JVM, this session exist until PC restarted,
- `JFrame#dispose()` terminating current JVM,
- `System#exit(int);` terminating current JVM,

better would be to [JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

don't suplly [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), maybe will be better use that directly